# What is the advantage of using post dates in my permalink structures?

Tags: seo, permalinks

I am trying to achieve the best permalink structure for my site. It will be a multi-author site where users will be posting artciles on a daily basis.

I want the permalink structure to be as follows:

```
http://sitename.com/username/postname
```

However, I have seen many sites that put the post date in the permalink like this:

```
http://sitename.com/username/postdate/postname
```

What would you advice me to do? 
Will I get any advanteges on using the post date in my permalink strcuture regarding SEO?

PS: I already checked out this answer [What is the best WordPress permalink structure for a website with daily new posts and updates?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/50943/what-is-the-best-wordpress-permalink-structure-for-a-website-with-daily-new-post) but I was not happy with it.

Comment: SEO is the only aspect you are interested in?

Comment: Mostly SEO, but I open to any advice regarding post dates in permalinks.

Comment: I see. For the "any advice" part, you may see [my answer](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/57997/17633) at the duplicate.